# WCF performance net.tcp versus namedpipes

Tags: wcf, performance

What the performance benefit is of switching from net.tcp to named pipes binding?

Asking since we have had some problems getting named pipes to work, and therefore wondering if it is worth the effort.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In chapter one of [Programming WCF Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491944838), Juval Lowy provides this flowchart for choosing the right binding:

[image]

Please see:

- [A Performance Comparison of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) with Existing Distributed Communication Technologies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx) - MSDN article.
- [What is the best choice for .NET inter-process communication?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84855/what-is-the-best-choice-for-net-inter-process-communication)
- [WCF Binding Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561915/wcf-binding-performance)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ... and conatent are links only